# extracting subcontents of a link

Tags: java, jsoup

How can I extract "read more" part of this news.When I uses jsoup it only gives before the contents of "read more" part.I want to extract entire contents of that news.

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String code=sc.nextLine();
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://ieee-link.org/category/events/" +code+ "/").get();
Elements els = doc.select("div.entry");
System.out.println(els.text());
```

Answer (score 0):

The read more seems to contain a link. You can extract the target of that link and get this URL as well with Jsoup:

```
Elements els = doc.select("div.entry");
//inside each els we can find something like: <a class="more-link" href="http://ieee-link.org/renesas/">Read More »</a>

for (Element el : els){
  Element anchor = el.select("a.more-link");
  if (anchor != null){
    Document moreDoc = Jsoup.connect(anchor.attr("href")).get();
    System.out.println(moreDoc);
  }
  else{
    System.out.println(el);
  }
}
```

Note, that this code is written out of my head. Some method names might be wrong. Spelling is also questionable.